# Importing a Unity3D Scene into an Android fragment

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, unity-game-engine

I've searched online for similar questions, and while I've found several similar questions, none had reliable answers, which is why I'm posting here.

When the Unity3D project is compiled for Android, it basically just gives the scene as an Activity that you can start/end/etc. I want to change this Activity into a Fragment in order to display it as a tab inside a navigation drawer, and as a sub-view inside another fragment/activity.

So basically I had a `MainActivity` with an Open button, and a `UnityPlayerNativeActivity` which is the actual Unity3D project.

I searched how to change a general activity to a fragment, and changed the `UnityPlayerNativeActivity` to match. For example, in the newly-titled `UnityPlayerNativeFragment` below (with comments reflecting what exactly was changed from before):

```
import com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer;
// Other imports available in full code linked to below

public class UnityPlayerNativeFragment extends Fragment
{
    // Changes in this class:
    // 1- 'this' references changed to "getActivity()"
    // 2- onCreate -> onCreateView
    // 3- protected -> public in function names
    // 4- @Override added before function calls
    // 5- newInstance and onAttach added

    protected UnityPlayer mUnityPlayer;     // don't change the name of this variable; referenced from native code
    private static final String ARG_SECTION_NUMBER = "section_number";

    public static UnityPlayerNativeFragment newInstance(int sectionNumber) {
        UnityPlayerNativeFragment fragment = new UnityPlayerNativeFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER, sectionNumber);
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }


    @Override
    public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
        super.onAttach(activity);
        ((HomeActivity) activity).onSectionAttached(
                getArguments().getInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER));
    }

    // UnityPlayer.init() should be called before attaching the view to a layout - it will load the native code.
    // UnityPlayer.quit() should be the last thing called - it will unload the native code.

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        //below line removed because it was causing errors
        //getActivity().requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);

        getActivity().getWindow().takeSurface(null);
        getActivity().setTheme(android.R.style.Theme_NoTitleBar_Fullscreen);
        getActivity().getWindow().setFormat(PixelFormat.RGB_565);

        mUnityPlayer = new UnityPlayer(getActivity());
        if (mUnityPlayer.getSettings ().getBoolean ("hide_status_bar", true))
            getActivity().getWindow ().setFlags (WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
                                   WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

        int glesMode = mUnityPlayer.getSettings().getInt("gles_mode", 1);
        boolean trueColor8888 = false;
        mUnityPlayer.init(glesMode, trueColor8888);

        View playerView = mUnityPlayer.getView();
        return playerView;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy ()
    {
        mUnityPlayer.quit();
        super.onDestroy();
    }

    // onPause()/onResume() must be sent to UnityPlayer to enable pause and resource recreation on resume.
    @Override
    public void onPause()
    {
        super.onPause();
        mUnityPlayer.pause();
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume()
    {
        super.onResume();
        mUnityPlayer.resume();
    }

    @Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig)
    {
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
        mUnityPlayer.configurationChanged(newConfig);
    }
}
```

The `AndroidManifest.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" package="com.SamerBekhazi.Test" android:versionName="1.0" android:versionCode="1" android:installLocation="preferExternal">
  <supports-screens android:smallScreens="true" android:normalScreens="true" android:largeScreens="true" android:xlargeScreens="true" android:anyDensity="true" />
  <application android:theme="@style/AppTheme" android:icon="@drawable/app_icon" android:label="@string/app_name">
    <activity android:launchMode="singleTask" android:label="@string/app_name" android:configChanges="fontScale|keyboard|keyboardHidden|locale|mnc|mcc|navigation|orientation|screenLayout|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|uiMode|touchscreen" android:screenOrientation="portrait" android:name=".HomeActivity">
      <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
      </intent-filter>
      <meta-data android:name="unityplayer.ForwardNativeEventsToDalvik" android:value="false" />
    </activity>
  </application>
  <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="14" android:targetSdkVersion="21" />
  <uses-feature android:glEsVersion="0x00020000" />
</manifest>
```

I only included those 2 files here because I figure the problem is from one or the other. The full code is downloadable [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B3H9tFePPUJBX2lwbjV1U3lsX28/view?usp=sharing). Extract/Import into Android Studio - you may need to press `Sync Project with Gradle Files` once for it to work.

The rest of the project is based on the `Navigation Drawer Activity` project that Android Studio auto-creates for you when creating a new project. I basically just call a `newInstance` of the above `UnityPlayerNativeFragment` when its corresponding icon is pressed in the `NavigationDrawer`.

What results when I press the tab for the scene: A black screen, with the Action Bar showing still, but nothing else. The top-right "Settings" button is still press-able, as is the Navigation Drawer button, but when one presses another tab on the Navigation Drawer, the entire app freezes and you have to force exit. I think the latter issue is because you can't close a `UnityPlayer` that hasn't opened properly, so the main issue is in actually making the `UnityPlayer` open up properly inside the Fragment. The rest of the app (the other tabs) work fine. I tried several variations (everything I could think of) in the above code and `AndroidManifest.xml` file, but nothing worked.

Logcat doesn't show any errors, it just says:

```
11-11 21:22:19.681  29280-29280/com.Bekhazi.Bouncy_Ball W/linker﹕ libmain.so has text relocations. This is wasting memory and is a security risk. Please fix.
11-11 21:22:19.681  29280-29280/com.Bekhazi.Bouncy_Ball D/dalvikvm﹕ Added shared lib /data/app-lib/com.Bekhazi.Bouncy_Ball-2/libmain.so 0x42d64cd8
11-11 21:22:19.691  29280-29280/com.Bekhazi.Bouncy_Ball W/linker﹕ libmono.so has text relocations. This is wasting memory and is a security risk. Please fix.
11-11 21:22:19.691  29280-29280/com.Bekhazi.Bouncy_Ball W/linker﹕ libunity.so has text relocations. This is wasting memory and is a security risk. Please fix.
```

What exactly is wrong here? The target build is for Android 5.0 and I'm using Android Studio 0.8.14.
Worth noting: I was able to successfully load the scene onto my Nexus 5 when it was an Activity.

Comment: Did you get this to work?

Comment: No, I ended up using something entirely different from Unity for various reasons.

Answer (score 2):

Try this way and it works at my side.

1.Create UnityPlayer at Activity

```
    private UnityPlayer mUnityPlayer;
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        mUnityPlayer = new UnityPlayer(this);
```

2.On Fragment

```js
    
    private MyActivity mUnityMainActivity;
    private UnityPlayer mUnityPlayer;
    View playerView;
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater,
            @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        mUnityMainActivity = (MyActivity) getActivity();
        mUnityPlayer = mUnityMainActivity.GetUnityPlayer();
        playerView = mUnityPlayer.getView();
        LayoutParams lp = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT);
        playerView.setLayoutParams(lp);
        if(playerView.getParent() != null){
            ((ViewGroup)playerView.getParent()).removeAllViews();
        }
        return playerView;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I managed to integrate it into a fragment with the help provided above and with this link: https://forum.unity.com/threads/unity3d-in-fragment.327303/.

It is essential to have the standard methods in the activity.

More elaborated below:

1. In the activity that holds the fragment (`MyActivity`):

- declare the variable UnityPlayer mUnityPlayer;
- this will trigger the import `import com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer;`
- add all the overriding code below

  ```
  //region Lifecycle methods
  @Override
  protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    mUnityPlayer = new UnityPlayer(this);
  }

  /** FOR UNITY **/
  @Override
  protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    mUnityPlayer.pause();
  }

  // Resume Unity
  @Override protected void onResume()
  {
    super.onResume();
    mUnityPlayer.resume();
  }

  // Low Memory Unity
  @Override public void onLowMemory()
  {
    super.onLowMemory();
    mUnityPlayer.lowMemory();
  }

  // Trim Memory Unity
  @Override public void onTrimMemory(int level)
  {
    super.onTrimMemory(level);
    if (level == TRIM_MEMORY_RUNNING_CRITICAL)
    {
        mUnityPlayer.lowMemory();
    }
  }

  // This ensures the layout will be correct.
  @Override public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig)
  {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    mUnityPlayer.configurationChanged(newConfig);
  }

  // Notify Unity of the focus change.
  @Override public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus)
  {
    super.onWindowFocusChanged(hasFocus);
    mUnityPlayer.windowFocusChanged(hasFocus);
  }

  // For some reason the multiple keyevent type is not supported by the ndk.
  // Force event injection by overriding dispatchKeyEvent().
  @Override public boolean dispatchKeyEvent(KeyEvent event)
  {
    if (event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_MULTIPLE)
        return mUnityPlayer.injectEvent(event);
    return super.dispatchKeyEvent(event);
  }

  // Pass any events not handled by (unfocused) views straight to UnityPlayer
  @Override public boolean onKeyUp(int keyCode, KeyEvent event)     { return mUnityPlayer.injectEvent(event); }
  @Override public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event)   { return mUnityPlayer.injectEvent(event); }
  @Override public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event)          { return mUnityPlayer.injectEvent(event); }

  /*API12*/ public boolean onGenericMotionEvent(MotionEvent event)  { return mUnityPlayer.injectEvent(event); }

  @Override
  protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    mUnityPlayer.quit();
  }
  ```

2. In the fragment:

- variable declaration private MyActivity myActivity;
- variable declaration: private UnityPlayer unityPlayer;
- this will trigger the "import com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer;"
- below code

  ```
  @Nullable
  @Override
  public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  myActivity = (MyActivity) getActivity();
  View unityPlayViewer = calibActivity.mUnityPlayer.getView();
  new Handler().postDelayed(() -> initialize(), 5000);
  return unityPlayViewer;
  }

  private void initialize() {
  calibActivity.mUnityPlayer.UnitySendMessage("your commands to Unity to start playing");
  }
  ```